# How To Get The ForEach Loop To Work On Deep Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying to get a forEach loop to write a table row that consists of a variable from both a shallow nested object and a deep nested object.

I have this JSON object:

```
var chardata = [{
    "moveList": [{
        "name"    : "Directional Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Motion Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Button Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for B" }]
    }]
}];
```

And this forEach function:

```
function buildSynergyTest(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('CharacterSynergy');
    var html = '\n';

    for (character of data) {
        character.moveList.forEach(function(move, i) {
            html += ` <TR>\n`;
            html += `  <TD>${move.name}</TD>\n`;
            html += `  <TD>${move.synergy[i].partner}</TD>\n`;
            html += `  <TD>${move.synergy[i].moveEqual}</TD></TR>\n`;
        });
    }
    
    table.innerHTML += html;
}

buildSynergyTest(chardata);
```

When I run the forEach loop, the first column translates perfectly. But the second and third columns do not. What's supposed to happen is this:

```
<TABLE border=1>
 <TR>
  <TD>Directional Test</TD>
  <TD>Character A</TD>
  <TD>Direct Synergy for A</TD></TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Motion Test</TD>
  <TD>Character A</TD>
  <TD>Motion Synergy for A</TD></TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Button Test</TD>
  <TD>Character A</TD>
  <TD>Button Synergy for A</TD></TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Directional Test</TD>
  <TD>Character B</TD>
  <TD>Direct Synergy for B</TD></TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Motion Test</TD>
  <TD>Character B</TD>
  <TD>Motion Synergy for B</TD></TR>
 <TR>
  <TD>Button Test</TD>
  <TD>Character B</TD>
  <TD>Button Synergy for B</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

Instead, I am getting one of two results:

1. The second and third columns of data (move.synergy.partner and move.synergy.moveEqual) are listed as undefined. But they are defined, all I have to do is a console.log of chardata[0].moveList[0].synergy[0].partner/moveEqual, and they would show up just fine.
2. If I were to put the [i] symbol in front of synergy, JS breaks with an undefined error. I know that [i] works in for loops, so I have to assume it should also work in this forEach, but for some reason it doesn't.

The only way I can bring up the desired values is hard coding, by deliberating putting a [0] or [1], but that defeats the purpose of the forEach loop.

How do I rewrite the forEach loop so that it can iterate all columns to be like the expected example?

Comment: you do realise you are accessing `chardata[0].moveList[0].synergy[0]` then `chardata[0].moveList[1].synergy[1]` then `chardata[0].moveList[2].synergy[2]` - oops `chardata[0].moveList[2]` only has two `synergy`

Comment: If you want two loops, you have to write two loops :)

Comment: Your `i` is the index of the `moveList` array you are looping over. Trying to use that _same_ index to access the items in the `synergy` arrays inside those objects - that simply makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: _"What's supposed to happen is this:"_ - you want all your `Character A` records there first, and the `Character B` records after that. You won't _get_ that, by only looping over `moveList` once.

Comment: If there is only ever going to be Character A and B - then you could simply loop over `moveList` twice - output the records for A in the first loop, and those for B in the second. If the number of characters could vary - then you should probably start with a loop over those instead. And if not all moves come with the _same_ amount of characters, then you would probably also have to determine the "full set" first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
var chardata = [{
    "moveList": [{
        "name"    : "Directional Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Motion Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Button Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for B" }]
    }]
}];

document.querySelector("table").innerHTML = chardata[0].moveList
 .flatMap(ml=>ml.synergy.map(s=>[ml.name,s.partner,s.moveEqual]))
 .sort(([,a],[,b])=>a.localeCompare(b))
 .map(r=>"<tr><td>"+r.join("</td><td>")+"</td></tr>")
 .join("\n");
```

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse}
td {border:1px solid grey;padding:4px}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#eee}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

In the first `.flatMap()` loop I collect all the nested subarrays into a flat array and re-arrange them slightly: the property `name` is inserted as a first element of the returned array, followed by the `partner` and `moveEqual` properties of the array in the `synergy` property.

The `.sort()` then sorts the array according to the second column ("Character A/B"). As the JavaScript sort function is now stable the original order of Directional, Motion and Button tests is maintained.

The `.map()` following the sort then creates some HTML that is evetually `.join()`ed  with a newline character and assigned to the `.innerHTML` of the first table in the document (feel free to insert an `#id` selector here instead).

Comment: I think `.sort(([_,a],[__,b])=>a.localeCompare(b))` can be `.sort(([,a],[,b])=>a.localeCompare(b))`

Comment: That is a really long line. I like it, though; it really works. I was originally going to do this without the sorting, but maybe I should keep it after all because the middle column is not what you think. I plan to incorporate this into a dropdown menu function where the character is an id that shows and hides all items associated with the character (ie: select Character A to bring up moveEquals only associated with Character A, and so on).

This is the one I'm marking as right.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more loop

```js
var chardata = [{
    "moveList": [{
        "name"    : "Directional Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Motion Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Button Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for B" }]
    }]
}];

function buildSynergyTest(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('CharacterSynergy');
    var html = '\n';

    for (character of data) {
        character.moveList.forEach(function(move, i) {
            html += ` <TR>\n`;
            html += `  <TD>${move.name}</TD>\n`;
            move.synergy.forEach(synergy => {
              html += `  <TD>${synergy.partner}</TD>\n`;
              html += `  <TD>${synergy.moveEqual}</TD></TR>\n`;
            })
        });
    }
    
    table.innerHTML += html;
}

buildSynergyTest(chardata);
```

```html
<table id="CharacterSynergy"></table>
```

Also, may be easier using `map`

```js
const chardata = [{
    "moveList": [{
        "name"    : "Directional Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Direct Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Motion Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Motion Synergy for B" }]
    },{
        "name"    : "Button Tests",
        "synergy" : [{ "partner" : "Character A", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for A" }, { "partner" : "Character B", "moveEqual" : "Button Synergy for B" }]
    }]
}];

function buildSynergyTest(data) {
    const table = document.getElementById('CharacterSynergy');
    
    const html = data.map(character =>
      character.moveList.map(move =>
          `<tr>
            <td>${move.name}</td>
            ${move.synergy.map(synergy =>
              `
              <td>${synergy.partner}</td>
              <td>${synergy.moveEqual}</td>
              `
            ).join('')}
          </tr>`
      ).join('')
    ).join('')
    
    table.innerHTML += html;
}

buildSynergyTest(chardata);
```

```html
<table id="CharacterSynergy"></table>
```

Comment: `You need two loops` ... you mean THREE of course

Comment: The table structure here doesn't match the expected output